# Difference between https url vs http url as oauth auth callback

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

According to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token, it is strongly recommended you use HTTPS for all OAuth authorization steps. However, I found out the callback url is not following this suggestion. Is there a difference if a https callback url is given vs a http callback url is given?

For example,

```
Request URL:
POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

Authorization Header:
oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%3A3005%2Ftwitter%2Fprocess_callback",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback URL just needs to in a url format, the Oauth spec does not mandate that it is https.

Certain Oauth providers (like SalesForce) do force the use of https.

Most service providers however just force you to register you callback url so that the service provider can verify that the correct callback url is provided during an oauth dance using your consumer key / secret.

Also, mobile apps in Android can create special protocol handlers, allowing callback handlers like "linkedin://callback" to be defined (to let the Android app handle linkedin oauth callbacks).

In that scenario it wouldn't make sense to force https, as it would force mobile apps to off-load their oauth dance to a remote server, where in some cases its perfectly acceptable to do it in the app itself.

Also keep in mind that whe the access token is compromised, people wishing to make secured api calls also need access to the consumer key / consumer secret.